# Change Jquery value depending on window size

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, resize, fixed

Please see the [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PJa4t/2/) where I am using a script to change an absolutely position div to fixed when the user scrolls past 300px. How am I able to change 300 depending on the size of its parent div?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
      var $cache = $('.getFixed'); 
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300 ) 
        $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
      else
        $cache.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '300px'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
});
```

I think a window resize function may be needed, though I am not sure how to pass a value into the scroll script to change where the user scrolls past.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer both parts of your question:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
      var $cache = $('.getFixed'); 
      var theHeight = $cache.parent().height();

      if ($(window).scrollTop() >  theHeight) 
        $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
      else
        $cache.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': theHeight+'px'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        var width = $(this).width();
        var parentWidth = $(this).offsetParent().width();
        var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
        $("#image").width(percent+"%");
    });
});
```

I used the `resize()` function to change the `div`'s width.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Also I was hoping to resize the div #image relative to the actual image inside of it. On a window resize the image changes inside due to backgrounf-size though I'm looking to have the div itself change proportionally inline with the image? Can you help? Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! However, I'm a bit confused as to what you require. The code above resizes the `div` ('image') based on the window's size. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I implemented your code which works when I manually change the parent div's height. Though when I resize the window the image shrinks but the div does not and therefore the black box div #scroll-element does not follow. I need the #image div to shrink with the image on resize so that the absolutely positioned div #scroll-element will always remain at the base of its parent div #image. Does that make sense? @Thauwa

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent of the $cache element then you can use $cache.parent();

If you want to get the height or width of an element then you can use $el.width(), $el.innerWidth(), $el.height(), $el.innerHeight()

You can use these to calculate the height of the image and the relevant position

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
      var $cache = $('.getFixed');
      var offsetTop = $('#image').height() + $('#image').offset().top;
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > offsetTop ) 
        $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
      else
        $cache.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top':  offsetTop + 'px'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
});
```